# what files or directories resides in my root partition

Tags: centos, filesystems, partition, lvm

```
[root@localhost ~]# lsblk 
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
vda             252:0    0   400G  0 disk 
├─vda1          252:1    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─vda2          252:2    0 360.7G  0 part 
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0 355.7G  0 lvm  /
  └─centos-swap 253:1    0     5G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
vdb             252:16   0  1000G  0 disk
```

In the above command, shows the 2 disks(vda && vdb) in my server.

In the `vda2`, there are 2 Logical Volume Manager.

I know the `centos-root` is my root file system, because mount point is `/`.

**Question 1**: In my opinion, `/home` should be `/` subdirectory, so `/` disk size = `/home` disk size + all other directories disk size.

**Question 2**: I don't know what files will put into `centos-root lvm`. For example, if I `mkdir /foo`, will this directory occupy my `centos-root lvm` disk space.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). Copy the text here and use code formatting instead.

Comment: Also, the copied text after editing  **does not** match your screenshot.  Please verify it.

Answer (score 1):

> In the vda2, there are 3 Logical Volume Manager.

No; in partition `vda2`, there are 2 Logical Volumes: `centos-root` and `centos-swap`.

> In my opinion, `/home` should be `/` subdirectory, so `/` disk size = `/home` disk size + all other directories disk size.

Yes, this appears to be the case, since `lsblk` does not show the `/home` directory being mounted anywhere, so `/home` resides in the same device as `/`.

> if I mkdir `/foo`, will this directory occupy my `centos-root` lvm disk space.

Yes; since `/foo` is a subdir of `/`, it will be stored in the `centos-root` Logical Volume.

Note that the volume `vdb` is not mounted and is, so far, unused.